# Guardar salida de runtime en java en una variable

Tags: java, android-studio, bash, sketchware

me gustaria saber si es que se puede de alguna manera guardar en una variable el resultado del comando escrito. Veran la variable "comando" es el comando en bash. Puedo guardar la salida en un txt mediante el mismo comando. Pero me guataria hacerlo desde el mismo codigo y almacenarlo en una variable. Aqui esta el codigo. Gracias de antemano.

```
String[] cmdline = { "sh", "-c", (comandos) }; 
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdline);
} catch (Exception s) {
    finishAffinity();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Una forma de obtener el resultado en una variable se realizaría de esta forma obteniendo el InputStream de la ejecución del comando:

```
Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
String[] cmdline = {"sh", "--help"}; //Comando y parametro a ejecutar.       
String resultado = "";

Process proc;
try {
    proc = runTime.exec(cmdline);
    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

    String s = null;
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        resultado += s;  //Guarda información en variable resultado.
    }

} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
}

System.out.println("Valor de resultado:\n" + resultado);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias mi estimado. Me has ayudado mucho. Pero igual funciona para android studio verdad? Seria de mucha ayuda. Perdon por la ignorancia pero es que no se mucho de java. Espero que me puedas ayudar, de antemano gracias muchas gracias.